# Giphy android sdk returns no data on release build

Tags: android, giphy

The sample code from giphy's [docs](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-android-sdk-core#trending-endpoint) for getting trending gif is

```
/// Trending Gifs
client.trending(MediaType.gif, null, null, null, new 
CompletionHandler<ListMediaResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(ListMediaResponse result, Throwable e) {
        if (result == null) {
            // Do what you want to do with the error
        } else {
            if (result.getData() != null) {  //Problem on release build
                for (Media gif : result.getData()) {
                    Log.v("giphy", gif.getId());
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("giphy error", "No results found");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This code works fine on development environment. But in release build `result.getData()` always returns `null`. Unable to figure it out whats the issue. I have tried with giphy's production key also but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add proguard rules for giphy

```
-keepclassmembernames class com.giphy.sdk.core.models.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class com.giphy.sdk.core.network.response.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn com.giphy.sdk.core.**
```