# GIPHY Android SDK does not return any GIFS on release build

Tags: android, obfuscation, giphy

I am integrating GIPHY Android SDK into our app (which is a keyboard), and on the debug release everything works fine and the GIFs are displayed correctly. However, on our release build, no GIFs are displayed; instead, a message of "NO RESULTS" is displayed:

[No GIFs on release build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeiVO.jpg)

I found another question here asking something similar ([Giphy android sdk returns no data on release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802222/giphy-android-sdk-returns-no-data-on-release-build)) and the answer was to include some *ProGuard* rules for the GIPHY libraries. However, our project does not use ProGuard obfuscation on the release build (uses *DashO*, instead).

¿Is there any special consideration that should be taken into account with GIPHY SDK on release build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of DashO are you using? DashO v10 integrates with R8 which uses the same ProGuard-based rules.
If you are using an earlier version, you should be able to create similar rules in DashO's configuration.

FYI, I work for PreEmptive on the DashO product.